# How to python script "Scale B-Bone"?

Tags: scripting, rigging

I want script "**Scale B-Bone**" to be in proportion to Bone Length. 
How do I access this property?

Note I am interested in **Scale BBone** and **Scale** please refer to bellow image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [pose bones](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.PoseBone.html) can be found at `bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones` with each bone having a length property `bones['Bone'].length` which represents the visible length in pose mode.

The bbone size that you change when using "Scale BBone" is two properties of the [armatures bones](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Bone.html) which can be accessed through `bones['Bone'].bone.bbone_x` and `bones['Bone'].bone.bbone_z`

```
import bpy

ratio = 0.3
pose_bones = bpy.date.objects['Armature'].pose.bones
b = pose_bones['Bone']

b.bone.bbone_x = 1 / b.length * ratio
b.bone.bbone_z = 1 / b.length * ratio
```

Comment: than you. But I want to Change "Scale BBone" and not Scale. How do i do that with script? pls see the screen shot i added