# Is it possible in blender to change the dimensions of a downloaded 3d model in .blend format or .obj format in blender using python scripting?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I am totally new to blender, I have downloaded a 3D model of a humanoid and am able to see it in blender. I want to change its dimensions and size in all perform editing on by changing its size, height, arm width, length, etc.
In a more clear picture of the question, suppose i have 5 persons whose 3D model I have to make automatically, so I want to change the dimensions of that humanoid to match the body measurements of these people. If I can mark those points manually on the humanoid and define parameters of shoulder width, arm length, height, etc and just input the values then my project can go a little forward.
The model I am using is attached in this link,
https://free3d.com/3d-model/rigged-male-human-442626.html
Please if anyone can tell me if it is possible to edit the model by defining certain parameters through python scripting. I need it as an add on for my project. And i just need to know how can i do that rest i shall experiment and do.

Comment: The language used here does not make much sense. You need to re-form the question in a clear and easy to understand manner and give it a descriptive title. Maybe start by describing what results you need and then tell us about what you are struggling with to achieve them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to python script "Scale B-Bone"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/how-to-python-script-scale-b-bone)

Comment: I don't think it's possible from a regular model you created or got by others. You would need a parametric modeling tool, which blender itself is not. You could alter some part of the mesh (or armature) by code, but that would create heavily distorted model, not what you wish to have, You probably need some tool like MakeHuman (and then import the model in blender), or a blender addon like Manuel Bastioni Lab. Those tools create new characters parametrically, and you can maybe automate them, but that's matter for another specific question, for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be waiting for the clarification of the question and will do my best to edit my answer accordingly because the question is really poorly formed, however if you need a way to generate different human characters quickly defining properties and measurements of their body parts, you will definitely find [ManuelBastioniLAB](http://www.manuelbastioni.com/manuellab.php) add-on interesting. It is a free and very well designed tool for parametric human character modeling.

Comment: First of all thankyou for extending a support hand sir, I am looking forward to develop a python script that could make changes in the size of the current 3d model according to the parameters I input for height, shoulder width, stomach width, etc, and these parameters would be some calibrated parameters varying from person to person. In all I want this 3D model to be edited using a script automatically such that it changes its built and size according to the body structure of the person under study.

Comment: You should edit your question and rewrite it in a more understandable way without grammar and spelling mistakes with this information included and a descriptive title if you want to get more answers. I do not know how else I could help you. ManuelBastioniLAB does exactly what you describe. You can have a look at MakeHuman software as well.

Comment: I checked ManuelBastioniLAB and currently working with it, also I am able to set those values of measurements with Python scripts, but I am still not sure whether it could be beneficial for my project or not because it has got a lot of object properties and the measurements we are inputting in it are also different, I wanted to adjust it to look like the person under study, but how will I caliberate so many measurement parameters it is having.

Comment: But thanks alot, as per my request and need you suggested something very good